# How to align form using css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to css and I would like to know how I would be able align my web page to look like something like this http://www.cosplayshopper.com/cosplay-accessories/naruto-accessories. See how the products are aligned above the text, I want something similar like that except using form. I already have the necessary html code for the css such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="order_css.css">
```

to link the css into the php. While searching through the web i found that I could use `<div class...>` and `<fieldset>`.

Comment: I would recommend start looking at the source code of the page. Also use browser's development tools, to see how css is computed. It should give you an idea of how css + html works

Comment: This is much too broad for stackoverflow.. Best to look at some tutorials for HTML/CSS and layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too general. It would be actually best for you to learn the basics of using float in css.

Anyway, I created a simple css for you. This may help http://jsfiddle.net/monnoval/c8keU/2/

The main thing to look at the my fiddle is this part

```
.container {width: 768px}
a.item {width: 240px; float: left; margin: 5px; height: 285px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not php..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="order_css.css">
```

This code is HTML ;-)

This code only imports the stylesheet `order_css.css` to your page.

You first should learn the basics of html/ css..

[Look here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss).